# Combine multiple list columns into one list column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

When working with a data.frame containing columns of lists, how can multiple columns of lists be combined so that their rowwise contents are combined into a single column of lists?

#### Example

Here's a two-column data.frame (both columns are columns of lists)

```
df <- structure(list(foo = list(c("foo1", "foo1.1"), "foo2", 
    "foo3"), bar = list("bar1", 
    "bar2", "bar3")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can we make a third column which is also a column of lists, but where each row contains the contents of the lists in the other two columns?

e.g. The first row would contain the 2 items in `df[1, 1]$foo` *and* the single item in `df[1,2]$bar`; that is, these three items in one list `foo1 foo1.1 bar` (and of course the same for the second row, third row and so on)

Note: I suspect the solution may involve purrr, however I am not certain

Comment: Is there a way to extend this question to three or more columns?  I prefer the dplyr purrr solution below but could certainly live with a base solution.

Comment: @ChuckP If you don't have too many columns, you can add them like so `df %>% mutate(foo_bar = map2(foo, bar, c))` becomes `df %>% mutate(new_col = map2(foo, bar, baz, qux, c))` for 4 columns. I had a quick look at trying to do it without having to name them (using `everything()` or `across()`) but couldn't get it working, may be worth another SO question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(foo_bar = mapply(c, foo, bar))

  foo       bar       foo_bar  
  <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <chr [2]> <chr [1]> <chr [3]>
2 <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [2]>
3 <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [2]>
```

Or with the addition of `purrr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(foo_bar = map2(foo, bar, c))
```

With multiple columns:

```
df %>%
 mutate(bar2 = bar) %>%
 mutate(res = pmap(across(everything()), c))

  foo       bar       bar2      res      
  <list>    <list>    <list>    <list>   
1 <chr [2]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [4]>
2 <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [3]>
3 <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [1]> <chr [3]>
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend this question to three or more columns?  I prefer the dplyr purrr solution below but could certainly live with a base solution.

Comment: Would like do know this too.

Comment: @spindoctor updated the post to accommodate more than two columns :)

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `Map`

```
df$foo_bar <-  do.call(Map, c(f = c, df))
```